# How Can I create Folder.htt in windows?

Tags: windows-7

How can I create Folder.htt in Windows7? 
Does it work in Windows7?

Answer (score 1):

You create it with any text editor – just click *Save* and enter `"Folder.htt"` as the name – and no, it won't have any effect in Windows 7. The support for customized folders has been disabled in Windows XP SP1 (can be [re-enabled](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/819028)) and completely removed in Windows Vista.

You can obtain the default `Folder.htt` from `%WINDIR%\Web` in older Windows versions; see also [this KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/181689) for some basic documentation.